# click button in activity 1 and if the button clicked show textview ... in activity 3

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-activity

The Title is just a example. In my first `Activity` i have 2 buttons. If u hit the first `Button` (`Button1`) you will visit `activity` 2.1. But when you hit the second `Button`(`Button2`) you will visit `Activity` 2.2. In `activity` 3 its neccessary to know which `Button` the user hitted (Button`enter code here`2 or 1) because they will be different `TextViews` to show. So how show this different `TextViews`?

**This Code is in `Activity` 3.**

```
 public void Button1 (View view) {
    TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nextText);
    if (txtView .getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void Button2 (View view) {
    TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nextText2);
    if (txtView .getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Send the button name as `putStringExtra` with `Intent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can set the `integer` value `1` or `2` according to the button clicked and then pass this `integer` from activity 1 to activity 2 and then activity 2 to activity 3, and check in activity 3 and set visibility according to the `integer` value.

**Example:**

On Button 1 Click:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("button", 1);
startActivity(i);
```

On Button 2 Click:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("button", 2);
startActivity(i);
```

And get this value in `onCreate` method of activity 2:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    int button = b.getInt("button");
}
```

And again pass this value to activity 3 so you will get to know which button was clicked with the help of the `integer` that you received.

**Solution 2:**

You can save the button number `integer` value in `SharedPreferences` on the click of button and retrieve that value in activity 3 and set visibility of the button according to the `integer` value.

**Example:**

Declare `editor` in your activity 1

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

Initialize `editor` in your activity's `onCreate` method.

```
editor = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

And on Button 1 Click:

```
editor.putInt("button", 1);
editor.apply();
```

And on Button 2 Click:

```
editor.putInt("button", 2); 
editor.apply();
```

Now declare `sharedPreferences` in your activity 3

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

Initialize `sharedPreferences` in your activity's `onCreate` method.

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And in activity 3 get the value of button

```
int button = sharedPreferences.getInt("button", 0);
```

and set visibility of the button according to the value of `button`

Comment: Well this was my first mind but idk how SharedPreferences with button works.

Comment: I'm glad that you found this answer useful and accepted this answer.

Comment: I got one more question.. i am sorry for that but how can i set the visible accoird to the value of button? In my mind it's working with if (button..) but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

On button click start activity and send data in intent.
Use Boolean flag to detect whether 1st button was clicked or not.

On First and Second Button click pass Boolean flag in Intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("BUTTON_1_CLICKED", true);
                startActivity(intent);
```

In your 3rd Activity get clicked button flag using Bundle

```
if (extras != null) {
            Boolean value = extras.getBoolean("BUTTON_1_CLICKED", false);
           activity
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On first button click

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, CurrentActivityName3.class);
    intent.putExtra("button_name","button1");
    startActivity(intent);
```

On Second button click

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, CurrentActivityName3.class);
    intent.putExtra("button_name","button2");
    startActivity(intent);
```

In Third Activity:

```
try {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.containsKey("button_name")) {

                String button_name = bundle.getString("button_name");
                if(button_name.equalsIgnoreCase("button1")){
                  //do here for button 1 from activity 1

                 }
                  if(button_name.equalsIgnoreCase("button2")){
                 //do here for button 2 from Activity 2.2

                 }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Ty but how can I show the textViews on the same Activity now?

Comment: textViews1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and textViews2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: set "Visible" which you want to show and set "gone" which one you want to hide

Comment: if(button_name.equalsIgnoreCase("button1")){
                  //do here for button 1 from activity 1

                 }
                  if(button_name.equalsIgnoreCase("button2")){
                 //do here for button 2 from Activity 2.2

                 }
            }

Comment: in this condition

Answer (score 0):

```html
use a tag in textview android:Tag="1" for first button and android:Tag="2" for second .if user click on the button get the tag  using txtView.getTag() and , in third activity sent the tag using Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.putExtra("tag",tagHere);
startActivity(....);

and receive it there in third activity  using    String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tag");
```